# Custom field info. in Search Engines

Tags: search, search-engine

Can I show custom field info. on Search Engine Pages?

For example, when I type the keyword "google" on Google Search Engine, along with the regular search results, I also get some more information such as CEO, Founded, Headquarters, Founder, etc.. on the right sidebar, similar to the below image.

[image]

And I wondered if I could ever show up my company information also like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have a website accessible by Google's indexing bots and your page(s) contain [Structured Data Markup](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/?rd=1&hl=en) providing such info, more specifically by [Customizing the Knowledge Graph](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/overview) for your company (and provided that Google's indexing service considers the info relevant enough to show up in search results, of course).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I've tried including the schemas in my homepage, and crawled it again, but still, i couldn't get required changes on search engine.

Comment: Google doesn't update search indexes immediately. The update speed depends on your site's ranking in Google's system, it may take weeks or even months. Typical SEO subject. See, for example, http://support.aarcade.net/how-do-i-update-or-change-the-google-search-results-for-my-site/.