# Google Search Result with indexed file and map

Tags: seo, google-search

When we google for some business, it is displaying the result with all page indexed and Map. What changes we need to do in our website to display in such way.

For example:

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=emhealth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom field info. in Search Engines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613565/custom-field-info-in-search-engines)

Answer (score -1):

For site links that displaying below the home page, Google will detect it automatically. Just focus on your SEO and Google will change it by itself.

For a map, you need to register on Google Business: https://www.google.com/business/

Comment: Thanks Alireza. I will wait for it.

Answer (score -1):

Google will index when you completely finished. when you doing local listing or local directory submission than your site map show SERPs.

Comment: If you want people to know about you, put your twitter handle and stuff in your profile.  Please do not clutter your answers with such things.

Comment: Thanks Emon. I will wait for it.